# How are objects represented in raymarching shaders

Tags: shaders, signed-distance-field, raymarching

How does one represent geometry in raymarching shader? Say I wanted to pass a tree of SDF primitive shaders. My current idea is to pass texture containing their positions as rgb and type as alpha channel but that seems to be quite crude method which additionaly forces me to use same type of blending between  all objects.

Comment: Lots of raymarching examples are available with full code to inspect, modify, and instantly view the results on [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=tag%3Draymarching). Have you investigated how they represent their geometry? Any questions about specific examples / use cases?

Comment: Hmm on shadertoy they do generate geometry via raymarching true. I am asking how to, at runtime, synthesize Signed Distance Field function and pass it to shader and if it's possible to do it apart from recompilation of shader ( which isn't all that bad either, since most objects at least stay in place, but I would prefer to avoid it)

Comment: Which aspects of the scene can change at runtime? If it's a small set, you may be able to expose those aspects as parameters in your SDF function. If you want a kind of general-purpose raymarcher that can handle any scene, you might want to throw out the idea of drawing it all with a single shader pass, and instead look at drawing [batches of] shapes using proxy geometry (eg draw a bounding cube with conventional rasterization, then use raymarching inside that cube to render the actual form/materials), and using the depth buffer to composite these separate draws together.

Comment: Thanks that would be only way I think. I mean at least u till someone cooks up sdf accelerator card.

Comment: I'll see if I can flesh that out as an answer, unless someone else beats me to it. :) (Feel free to do so — answers are open to everyone)

Comment: Yes that would be good. I only asked after looking for a better part of day on some documents about it and it wasnt clear if that is possible or not. On unrelated note raymarching accelerator would be nice. Though I always was biased towards that metod of rendering.